# Constructing objects for a user-defined generic Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

If I defined my own generic array with this constructor:

```
public PublisherGenericArray(Class<E> c, int s)
{   
    // Use Array native method to create array  
    // of a type only known at run time
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final E[] a = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, s);
    this.a = a;
}
```

How do I create an object that satisfies the first parameter (class  c)?

Basically:

```
PublisherGenericArray <String> newArray = new <String> PublisherGenericArray(???,newSize);
```

What would go in the first parameter labeled "???"

Comment: Your `<String>` in `new <String> Publis...` serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of your construction is a class of the *parametrised type*.

The *parametrised type* is the invocation of the *generic type*. For example

`Foo<T>` is a generic type, while in

```
Foo<Integer> t;
```

the `Foo<Integer>` is a parametrised type.

In your code, `E` is a parameter type (variable type)

there are **infinity** number of possible constructions. To list some:

```
PublisherGenericArray<Integer> t = new PublisherGenericArray<Integer>(Integer.class, 3);
    PublisherGenericArray<String> tt = new PublisherGenericArray<String>(String.class, 3);
    PublisherGenericArray<NullPointerException> ttt = new PublisherGenericArray<>(NullPointerException.class, 3);
```

notice in the `ttt`, i have used **The Diamond** and it just works with java SE 7 and later

You can also create your parametrised type by doing the invocation on a *raw type* as well

```
class A<T> {
        }
        PublisherGenericArray<A> tttt = new PublisherGenericArray<A>(
                A.class, 4);
```

Comment: Good examples! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
PublisherGenericArray<String> newArray = new PublisherGenericArray<String>(String.class, newSize);
```